# call a function with multiple outputs defined in another file in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, call

Let assume that I have file named Input.py that have the following function:

```
import pandas as pd    

def fun_input(fName)
     ind = pd.read_excel(fName)
     p1 = ind[0]
     p2 = ind[1]
```

Now, I like to call this function in another file named Main.py and use the values of p1 and p2 for a given value of fName (that I will define in the main file). I have written a code like below but I am not how I should make it works. Please help me.

```
from Input import fun_input

fName = '1.xlsx'
p1 = fun_input(fName).p1
p2 = fun_input(fName).p2
```

Comment: It is _not_ possible to access a function's local variables. They disappear as soon as the function returns. The way to return data from a function is to use the `return` statement.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd    

def fun_input(fName)
     ind = pd.read_excel(fName)
     return ind[0], ind[1]
```

In the other file

```
from Input import fun_input

fName = '1.xlsx'
p1, p2 = fun_input(fName)
```

Comment: Can't you just `return ind[:1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "return" to return the values? Don't know if 'I'm missing something, seems too trivial haha. But maybe this:

```
def fun_input(fName)
     ind = pd.read_excel(fName)
     p1 = ind[0]
     p2 = ind[1]
     return {'p1':p1,'p2':p2}
returnValues=fun_input(fname)
p1 = returnValues['p1']
p2 = returnValues['p2']
```